# implement json in xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

"Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Service.View.Login+Success]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.\nTo fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.\nPath 'success', line 1, position 11."

```
        try
        {
            using (var cl = new HttpClient())
            {
                var formcontent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
                    {
                    new KeyValuePair<string,string>("email", email.Text),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password",passwors.Text)
                });


                var request = await cl.PostAsync("http://192.168.1.122/api/login/user", formcontent);

                request.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                var response = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                var myData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Success>(response);

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Error", ex.Message, "Close");
        }
```

Comment: Please reformat your question.

Comment: What's stopping you from doing exactly what the error message suggests?

Comment: **when I run this code show below error message**

Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Service.View.Login+Success]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.\nTo fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the ........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Check what response you get from the URL and correct your model.**

Next time when you have to deal with JSON and you want to quickly generate the C# models use services like https://app.quicktype.io.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is your MODEL (that you should post). It seems you try to deserialize an object (that is not an Array) inside an object that is an Array (or a List...).